# Rails: How can I set the route for a method which doesn't require an :id parameter but instead requires 2 query parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a table of listings, with a Model of Listing and a listings_controller class. I wrote a method which requires 2 parameters: latitude and a longitude. It then retrieves listings that are around 5 kms around that coordinate. In the listings_controller this is that method I wrote:

```
def around
  lat = params[:latitude]
  long = params[:longitude]
  @surroundings = Listing.where("latitude = ? and longitude = ?", lat, long)     
end
```

What I would like to do is have a url set up in my routes.rb file which when invoked by the client browser would supply a latitude and a longitude as 2 parameters. No :id parameter can be supplied since the client browser doesn't know the id and moreever there may not be any entry in the database with an exact match to the coordinates. Remember Im only looking to search for listings around the coordinates specificified.

So how do I write this in the routes file?

Here is the output of my "rake routes" command

```
    listings        /                                      listings#index
             GET    /listings(.:format)                    listings#index
             POST   /listings(.:format)                    listings#create
 new_listing GET    /listings/new(.:format)                listings#new
edit_listing GET    /listings/:id/edit(.:format)           listings#edit
     listing GET    /listings/:id(.:format)                listings#show
             PUT    /listings/:id(.:format)                listings#update
             DELETE /listings/:id(.:format)                listings#destroy
                    /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action
```

And this is how my routes.rb file looks:

```
Businesses::Application.routes.draw do

root to: 'listings#index', as: 'listings'

resources :listings
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

This is what I was hoping to use as a url string from the client browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/listings/around?latitude=XXX&longitude=XXXX
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got mostly everything in order already, the only question is how to generate the actual URL. The way I see it you have 2 options:

1. Just use the paths you have already:

   ```
   listings_path( :latitude => lat, :longitude => lng )
   ```

   This will work and generate a path like `/listings?latitude=XXX&longitude=XXX`
2. If you want the `/listings/around?...` version you can add it like this:

   ```
   # routes.rb
   resources :listings do
     collection do
       get :around
     end
   end
   ```

   Then you can make your url like this:

   ```
   around_listings_path( :latitude => lat, :longitude => lng )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try set up "around" action as collection:

```
resources :listings do
  get :around, :on => :collection
end
```

And in your view

```
=link_to around_listings_path(:latitude => lat, :longitude => long)
```